# Add an "Article in Press" watermark like in a research paper

Tags: backgrounds, watermark

Like research papers I want to put something like "Article in Press" between the texts. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Please don't. It makes the text very hard to read. (Especially in the case of the journal I recently reviewed for, which put a pale blue watermark on every page of the manuscript, which stood out so strongly that reading the text gave me a headache. Thankfully, there were no colour diagrams in the paper so I was able to print it in black and white.)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this helps:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\title{This will be a great article}
\author{The author}
\usepackage{draftwatermark} % one of the packages that can be used for watermarks, as shown below
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\SetWatermarkText{Article in Press} % Text to be printed across the page
\SetWatermarkScale{3} % Size of the watermark text
% further options include
% \SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{0,0,1} % choose color of watermark, default is 80% grey
%
% For more information see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/draftwatermark
%
\abstract{An article that has not been printed yet.}
\section{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to this site! I know that the OP didn't post any code, but we prefer the answers to be complete minimal document. You can pretty much inspire yourself in the answer of Gonzalo, and use the `lipsum` package to generate enough dummy material ;)

Comment: Thank you for the kind welcome and for your comment @yo' . I tried to improve my post and I hope that it will be more useful now. I wasn't aware of the `lipsum`package. I realize that it could have saved me some copy & pasting. Thanks for this information. If you have further suggestions for improvements I'll be glad and thankful to know.

Comment: Thank you.......but is not working over image. it is only working over texts

Comment: @DeepeshPatel Things can't work over images with white backgrounds (rather than transparent backgrounds). You have to make sure that your white is actually not white but transparent. Then it will work.

Comment: @RHertel Looks good to me now :-)

Comment: @DeepeshPatel For an option overlaying images, see the second part of my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=5,opacity=0.75,color=gray]{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={\sffamily Article in Press}}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

The resulting document:

[image]
If you want to overlay images, here's an option using TikZ and [`xwatermark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xwatermark):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\tikz\node[opacity=0.75,scale=6,text=gray,font=\sffamily]{Article in Press};}
\newwatermark*[allpages,angle=60,xpos=0,ypos=0]{\usebox\mybox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Please not in bright colours, if anyone is supposed to read the document!

Comment: @DavidRicherby Edited to use a darker color.